# Catch Exception Strategy not getting called for simple scenario of read a file..error on dataMapper...move files to error folder

Tags: mule

(Further update today: CathcExcpetionStratey for the flow is not triggered for exception coming out from the DataMapper processor. Exception coming from other components ARE getting caught as expected. It sounds like a bug with DataMapper! We are using 3.5.x Mule. Anyone else come across this?)

I have a simple use case of "read xml files from a folder, use dataMapper to transform it to another format...once done, move this file to processed folder". This works great. But then I added CatchExceptionStrategy to "catch all errors with datamapper (or otherwise), and in this section, move the erroring xml file to the errors folder.
My problem is that the CatchExceptionStrategy is not called. The console shows the error occurring....but CatchExceptionStragey is not called. Here is the flow...

```
 <flow name="FLOW_xml" doc:name="FLOW_xml" doc:description="this using XML in and customer format output">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\inpath" pollingFrequency="5000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="XML Folder Source" />

    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String "/>

    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="DataMapper_XmlToInternal" stream="true" pipeSize="5000" doc:name="DataMapper_XmlToInternal">
        <data-mapper:input-arguments>
            <data-mapper:input-argument key="SourceType">XML</data-mapper:input-argument>
            <data-mapper:input-argument key="SourceFileName">#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]</data-mapper:input-argument>
        </data-mapper:input-arguments>
    </data-mapper:transform>

    <file:outbound-endpoint path="D:\outpath" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']+'.json']" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FilePathToInternal"/>

     <response>
            <logger message="++++END OF PROCESS REACHED++++" level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"/> 
      </response>

    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <set-payload value="Error has occurred....." doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <logger level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger" message="Exception caught... #[message.payload]"/>

    </catch-exception-strategy>

</flow>
```

Looks like it should be simple as that. The same approach works with HTTP inboud/outbound example....on error it goes to CES section and executes custome output.

Can anyone tell whether theres something wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

If streaming mode is enabled the transfirmation is lazy and won't raise the exception. This is a known limitation.

Please try without streaming mode.